# Color for button for action.showCard Adaptive Card doesn't changes

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

Here is the image of the adaptive card, have a look it will better explain the question[image: 1]

we have built an app for MS teams, this app uses adaptive card in its flow, in the first step  a number of images are shown, there are different categories buttons at the top from there client can select images, for each button we have attached action.showCard, so except the last button all other buttons are of the same color but the last one is of different color, this looks bad for the client. I have not used any style for action.showCard but still it shows different color. can anyone help to remove the color from the last button? Thanks in advance

Card Json

```
{
"task": {
    "type": "continue",
    "value": {
        "title": "Select a non-monetary award",
        "height": "medium",
        "width": "medium",
        "card": {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "version": "1.2",
                "body": [],
                "actions": [{
                    "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                    "title": "SELF CARE",
                    "card": {
                        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                        "version": "1.2",
                        "body": [{
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [{
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": "stretch",
                                "separator": true,
                                "spacing": "medium",
                                "style": "default",
                                "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                                "verticalContentAlignment": "center",
                                "bleed": false,
                                "items": [{
                                    "type": "Image",
                                    "url": "https://image",
                                    "size": "Large",
                                    "altText": "Health Warrior",
                                    "selectAction": {
                                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                                        "title": "Health Warrior",
                                        "data": {
                                            "x": 2,
                                            "Recipients": null,
                                            "WorkFlow": null,
                                            "badgeId": 1395,
                                            "approverId": null,
                                            "tags": null,
                                            "awardValue": null,
                                            "comment": null,
                                            "businessJustification": null,
                                            "msteams": null
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                                    "separator": true
                                }, {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Health Warrior",
                                    "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                                    "size": "large",
                                    "maxLines": 15,
                                    "id": null,
                                    "color": null,
                                    "wrap": true
                                }, {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "",
                                    "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                                    "size": "medium",
                                    "maxLines": 10,
                                    "id": null,
                                    "color": "Dark",
                                    "wrap": false
                                }]
                            }],
                            "horizontalAlignment": "left",
                            "bleed": false,
                            "style": "emphasis"
                        }],
                        "style": "emphasis"
                    },
                    "style": "positive"
                }, {
                    "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                    "title": "PERFORMANCE",
                    "card": {
                        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                        "version": "1.2",
                        "body": [{
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [{
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": "stretch",
                                "separator": true,
                                "spacing": "medium",
                                "style": "default",
                                "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                                "verticalContentAlignment": "center",
                                "bleed": false,
                                "items": [{
                                    "type": "Image",
                                    "url": "https://image",
                                    "size": "Large",
                                    "altText": "Great Job",
                                    "selectAction": {
                                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                                        "title": "Great Job",
                                        "data": {
                                            "x": 2,
                                            "Recipients": null,
                                            "WorkFlow": null,
                                            "badgeId": 6,
                                            "approverId": null,
                                            "tags": null,
                                            "awardValue": null,
                                            "comment": null,
                                            "businessJustification": null,
                                            "msteams": null
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                                    "separator": true
                                }, {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Great Job",
                                    "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                                    "size": "large",
                                    "maxLines": 15,
                                    "id": null,
                                    "color": null,
                                    "wrap": true
                                }, {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "",
                                    "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                                    "size": "medium",
                                    "maxLines": 10,
                                    "id": null,
                                    "color": "Dark",
                                    "wrap": false
                                }]
                            }, {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": "stretch",
                                "separator": true,
                                "spacing": "medium",
                                "style": "default",
                                "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                                "verticalContentAlignment": "center",
                                "bleed": false,
                                "items": [{
                                    "type": "Image",
                                    "url": "https://image",
                                    "size": "Large",
                                    "altText": "Thank You!",
                                    "selectAction": {
                                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                                        "title": "Thank You!",
                                        "data": {
                                            "x": 2,
                                            "Recipients": null,
                                            "WorkFlow": null,
                                            "badgeId": 11,
                                            "approverId": null,
                                            "tags": null,
                                            "awardValue": null,
                                            "comment": null,
                                            "businessJustification": null,
                                            "msteams": null
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                                    "separator": true
                                }, {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Thank You!",
                                    "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                                    "size": "large",
                                    "maxLines": 15,
                                    "id": null,
                                    "color": null,
                                    "wrap": true
                                }, {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "",
                                    "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                                    "size": "medium",
                                    "maxLines": 10,
                                    "id": null,
                                    "color": "Dark",
                                    "wrap": false
                                }]
                            }],
                            "horizontalAlignment": "left",
                            "bleed": false,
                            "style": "emphasis"
                        }],
                        "style": "emphasis"
                    },
                    "style": "positive"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}[image]

Comment: Hey Priyank, can you add your card json to the question maybe? Its easier to answer and help you if we know the actual card.

Comment: Hello @TimCadenbach, I have added card json and also added the image of the new card json result, as the previous image card json was too big to analysis therefore I removed the first action.ShowCard.